# How to implement delta E color difference method of an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have implemented LMS Daltonization and have converted the RGB image into L*a*b color space . Now I want to compare the input and the output images using the standard method of Delta E. Can anyone please provide me with some heads regarding this method and how to carry on the comparison using MATLAb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple methods for calculating Delta E, with [formulas provided here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference).

Here is some source code to get you started:

- [CIE76 on FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31118-color-segmentation-by-delta-e-color-difference/content/DeltaE.m)
- [CIEDE2000 on FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24372-de2000/content/deltaE.m)